# How to Make a Scrollable Div Take the Remaining Space in a Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have these basic snippets. I would like for `.orange` to scroll when it fills with too much content. I also need `.orange` to be compressed first to its minimum height when the screen is shrunk, and only after should the two children overflow `.root`. Furthermore, when I add content to `.orange`, I don't want it to change the size of anything else.

I'm not sure how to achieve this, I've researched everywhere but cannot find any answers. I also cannot set a `max-height` to `.orange`, I simply want it to take up the rest of the container via `flex: 1;`.

https://codepen.io/Sean713/pen/VwBeEyP

```css
.root {
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.blue {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.white {
  height: 50px;
}

.orange {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 30px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* ________________STYLING_______________ */

.root {
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.blue {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.white {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.orange {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="blue">
    <div class="white">
      I have fixed height (panel)
    </div>
    <div class="orange">
      <p>I have a minimum height</p>
      <p>And I can scroll</p>
      <p>And I can scroll</p>
      <p>And I can scroll</p>
      <p>And I can scroll</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, a flex item cannot be smaller than the size of its content, thus the `min-height` value for the `.blue` container is set to `auto`.
Setting it to a different value (such as `min-height: 0`) should resolve this issue.

Comment: Legend- that did fix it. But I don't understand why this is the case? Since I'm not asking `.blue` to ever be smaller than its content in the first place, rather I'm asking its content to continue shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

If an element has flex: 1, this means the size of all of the other elements will have the same width as their content, but the element with flex: 1 will have the remaining full space given to it

remove flex:1 from your .orange class

```css
.root {
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.blue {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.white {
  height: 50px;
}

.orange {
  height: 30px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* ________________STYLING_______________ */

.root {
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.blue {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.white {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.orange {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="root">
  <div class="blue">
    <div class="white">
      I have fixed height (panel)
    </div>
    <div class="orange">
      <p>I have a minimum height</p>
      <p>And I can scroll</p>
      <p>And I can scroll</p>
      <p>And I can scroll</p>
      <p>And I can scroll</p>
      <p>And I can scroll</p>
      <p>And I can scroll</p>
      <p>And I can scroll</p>
      <p>And I can scroll</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```